# Superfish dropdowns - apply to only one top-level LI possible?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, superfish

I am applying Superfish to a menu, but only one top-level LI actually requires it, I would prefer the other LI items not to have it!

Since wordpress PHP is generating the source  I thought of one way to do it - just use JQuery to remove any UL inside the other top-level LI items.

```
$('#navmain > li').each(function(index) {

    if($(this).attr('id' ) !== 'menu-item-14') {
        $(this).find('ul').remove();
    }
});
```

Is there a better way with Superfish however? i.e. a callback perhaps where I can pass it the LI id of the one I want to dropdown?

Comment: Can you make an example in jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: I think my method is correct actually, just to remove with jQuery the other sub-menus. Superfish is JQuery anyway so it solves it. My code is simply a standard output of a main-menu from Wordpress ul > li > ul > li etc.